# Integrate and Plot function in R

Tags: r, function

I'm looking to plot temperature T (y axis) as a function of position x (x axis).

KNOWN:

x = -1500 * (2T + 0.0003 T^2)

DESIRED OUTPUT:

A plot of x vs T.

There is no dataset.

Comment: Please clarify the statement that you cannot use algebra??? Also I see nothing in the question body about integration.

Comment: Well to solve for the form h(y) you cannot use algebraic tactics. Raising both sides to the exp() will leave you with exp(hy) on the LHS. You will not be able to factor h. An iterative approach is then required. Apologies for the

Comment: Apologies for leaving out the part with integration. Including it would have made the question confusing and complex, and I performed the integration beforehand.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is insufficient information here to help you. For instance, I have no idea what data is *known* and what is *unknown* at the start. Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) using a minimal working dataset. Include sample data. Include expected (or desired) output.